# Slowing down responses in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using Express over Node.js and I'm currently writing loading views for my app (a screen that will show up when data is being fetched) but when I'm testing in local there are, obviously, no delays from the server and I can't see if the screens are working.

Is it possible to introduce a delay in Node.js for all responses without having to add a setTimeout for each response?

I tried slow-proxy, but it fails to load the absolute paths in the HTML (e.g. /img/item.png is mapped as such instead of /proxy/2000/img/item.png).

Comment: I may be wrong, but couldn't you add a middleware that runs something like `setTimeout(function () { next() }, 1000);` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In express/connect just put this above other middleware:

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
  setTimeout(next, 2000)
});
```

And a coffeescript version:

```
app.use (res,req,next)-> setTimeout(next,2000)
```

Comment: Thanks! So simple I couldn't see it